# Understanding Stanford SUTime output tags

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Can anyone explain the meanings of tags used by `SUTime`? Or in other sense how to `parse the output` of SUTime? It would be great if someone provide the link also.
I am using SUTime with `Java`.

Answer (score 1):

There is some basic documentation on the [SUTime homepage](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml#Usage).

That page links to more information on the annotation standard: [TIMEX3 standard](http://www.timeml.org/site/publications/timeMLdocs/timeml_1.2.1.html#timex3).